# How is best way to show content in specific order?

Tags: bash

Using bash how is best way to show content in specific order?
I have 2 files.txt, each file contains:

```
File1 
A 
B 
C

File2
D
E
F
```

Now I need to show this way:

```
output
A
D
B
E
C
F
```

I did this exercise in another language
but I'm having trouble converting in bash.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `paste`:

```
paste -d $'\n' File1 File2
```